# Enable an applescript from a menubar application?

Tags: xcode, applescript, menubar

I have successfully built a menubar application with a dropdown menu displaying text. I was wondering if there is a way to create a button that enables/disables an AppleScript. Like the time machine button. Options to select and it acts on that. I have tried everything I know but my experience with xcode is limited. If anyone here can help me out it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!:)

Comment: All UI elements of `NSStatusItem` can be views (`NSView`). So almost everything is possible,

Comment: Show what you tried